# Degree two homogeneous differentiable function is a quadratic form.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$ be a ${\cal C}^2$ function such that $f(tx) = t^2f(x)$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$ and all $x \in \Bbb R^n$. Then there is a bilinear map $B: \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^k$ such that $f(x) = B(x,x)$, for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

Here's some progress. Using some reverse engineering, we can say what $B$ must be. If $\Delta$ is the diagonal inclusion, differentiating $f = B \circ \Delta$ at $x$ and evaluating at $y$ gives $B(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}{\rm d}f(x)(y)$.

Then we're only left with proving that $B$ defined by that expression is linear in the first variable. We know that the maps $$\begin{matrix} \Bbb R \times \Bbb R^n & \stackrel{q \times f}{\longrightarrow} & \Bbb R \times \Bbb R^k &  \stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow} & \Bbb R^k \\ (t,x) & \mapsto & (t^2,f(x)) & \mapsto & t^2f(x)\end{matrix} \quad \text{ and }\quad \begin{matrix} \Bbb R \times \Bbb R^n & \stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow} & \Bbb R^n  & \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} & \Bbb R^k \\ (t,x) & \mapsto & tx & \mapsto & f(tx)\end{matrix}  $$are equal (yes, I'm abusing notation using $m$ twice). Differentiating $m \circ (q \times f) = f \circ m$ at $(t,x)$ gives: $${\rm d}m(t^2,f(x))\circ ({\rm d}q(t)\times {\rm d}f(x)) = {\rm d}f(tx)\circ {\rm d}m(t,x).$$Applying both sides on some $(s,y)$ gives (after a couple of steps): $$t^2 {\rm d}f(x)(y) + 2ts f(x) = t {\rm d}f(tx)(y) + s {\rm d}f(tx)(x).$$Making $s = 0$ we obtaing $t{\rm d}f(x) = {\rm d}f(tx)$ for all $t \neq 0$. Since ${\rm d}f(0) = 0$ (easy to check), we actually have ${\rm d}f(tx) = t{\rm d}f(x)$ for all real $t$.

- I don't know how to prove that ${\rm d}f(x_1+x_2) = {\rm d}f(x_1)+{\rm d}f(x_2)$;
- I don't know where does $f$ being ${\cal C}^2$ comes in. So far it seems that differentiability is enough.

Help?

Comment: (+1) No definitive ideas, but 1. It's sufficient to handle the case $k = 1$ ($f$ real-valued) by arguing componentwise; 2. If $B$ is _symmetric_, the polarization identity gives$$B(x, y) = \tfrac{1}{2}\bigl[f(x + y) - f(x) - f(y)\bigr].$$(That's the standard trick for recovering a symmetric bilinear form from the induced quadratic form.) Time permitting I'll think about this, but if these ideas are helpful you'll probably find a solution before I do. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $f \in \mathcal{C}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $\forall (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: f(tx)=t^{2}f(x)$, differentiating the map $f_{x}(t):=f(tx)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ fixed twice yields

$$\frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}} f_{x}(t)=(\partial_{i} \partial_{j}f)(tx)x^{i}x^{j}\stackrel{\text{homogeneity}}{=}2f(x).$$

This implies that $\frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}} f_{x}(t)$ is independent of $t$, and therefore $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{i} \partial_{j}f)(0)x^{i}x^{j},$$

which makes it clear that $B(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{i} \partial_{j}f)(0)x^{i}y^{j}$ fulfills the demands (and is even symmetric).